# Python - How to speed up smoothness in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, clock, cycle

I'm wondering how to speed up the smoothness of my code written in Python using pygam. I'm guessing I have to make this more efficient somehow? When this is run, some balls move around randomly in a set area, however, the new position of each ball is not smooth at all, there is a jump between each movement as the cycle is very slow. How do I fix this? Or is there any suggestions on how to improve it?
This is my code so far:

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
import random
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 800, 600
screen = display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Year 12: Ideal Gas Simulation")


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE=(255,255,255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BALLX = 0
BALLY = 1
BALLSPEEDX = 2
BALLSPEEDY = 3
List=[]
radius=5

running=True
myClock=time.Clock()


myClock.tick(60)
def initBall():


        for n in range(40):
            ballx = random.randint(0, 800) # randomly setting the x position
            bally = random.randint(0, 600) # randomly setting the y position
            dirx = random.randint(-5,5)    # randomly setting the x speed
            diry = random.randint(-5,5)    # randomly setting the y speed

            data=[ballx, bally, dirx, diry]
            List.append(data)
            # returning a list with all the data the ball needs
        return List # returning the list


def drawScreen(List):
    draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (0, 0, 800, 600))
    for x in range(40):
        BALLX=List[x][0]
        BALLY=List[x][1]
        draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (BALLX,BALLY),radius)
        display.flip()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (100-radius,100-radius,600+(2*radius),400+(2*radius)), 1)

        f=pygame.font.SysFont(None,60)
        text=f.render("PV=nRT",True,(0,0,0))
        screen.blit(text,(300,height/20))


def moveBall(List):
    for x in range(40):
        BALLX=List[x][0]
        BALLY=List[x][1]
        SPEEDX=List[x][2]#####data[BALLX]== the first index of each list [x][0]
        SPEEDY=List[x][3]##data[BALLSPEEDX]= List[x][2]
        age=SPEEDX+BALLX
        List[x][0]=age
         # increases the position of the ball
        plus=SPEEDY+BALLY
        List[x][1]=plus
    # checks to see if the ball is hitting the walls in the x direction
        if BALLX > 700:
            List[x][0] = 700#NORMALLY 800
            third=List[x][2]
            answer=third*-1
            List[x][2]=answer
        elif BALLX < 100:#NORMALLY 0
            List[x][0] = 100
            third=List[x][2]
            answer=third*-1
            List[x][2]=answer

    # checks to see if the ball is hitting the walls in the y direction
        if BALLY < 100:
            List[x][1] = 100#NORMALLY 0
            third=List[x][3]
            answer=third*-1
            List[x][3]=answer
        elif BALLY > 500:
            List[x][1] = 500#NORMALLY 600
            third=List[x][3]
            answer=third*-1
            List[x][3]=answer
    return List#return updated list


List=initBall()
while running==True:
    for evnt in event.get():
        if evnt.type==QUIT:
            running=False
            quit()
        if evnt.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mx,my=evnt.pos
            button=evnt.button

    drawScreen(List)
    List=moveBall(List)
```

Comment: you would be more comfortable by replacing `for x in range(40)` by `for ball in List:` and then call `ball[0]`,  `ball[1]`... everywhere

Comment: You can post your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get more tips.

Comment: Please post your code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. There are a lot of things that could be improved in your example as well as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to skrx's answer, you can also refactor the code and avoid a lot of duplicate calls. Also, indexing the `BALLS` array directly might improve performance slightly.

Generally, avoid naming variables inside functions with uppercase. These names are typically given to constants defined at the top of your file.

The version I came up with is below:

```
import array
import pygame
pygame.init()
import random

from pygame import *

size = WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
screen = display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Year 12: Ideal Gas Simulation")


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BALLX = 0
BALLY = 1
BALLSPEEDX = 2
BALLSPEEDY = 3
RADIUS = 5

BALLS = []

myClock = time.Clock()

myClock.tick(60)
def initBalls():
    for n in range(40):
        props = array.array('i', [
            random.randint(0, WIDTH),
            random.randint(0, HEIGHT),
            random.randint(-5, 5),
            random.randint(-5, 5),
        ])
        BALLS.append(props)


def drawScreen():
    draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (0, 0, 800, 600))
    props = (100-RADIUS, 100-RADIUS, 600+(2*RADIUS), 400+(2*RADIUS))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, props, 1)
    f = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 60)
    text = f.render("PV=nRT", True,(0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(text,(300, HEIGHT / 20))
    for i in range(len(BALLS)):
        draw.circle(screen, GREEN, BALLS[i][:2],RADIUS)
    display.flip()


def moveBalls():
    for i in range(len(BALLS)):

        if BALLS[i][0] > 700:
            BALLS[i][0] = 700
            BALLS[i][2] *= -1
        elif BALLS[i][0] < 100:
            BALLS[i][0] = 100
            BALLS[i][2] *= -1
        else:
            BALLS[i][0] += BALLS[i][2]

        if BALLS[i][1] < 100:
            BALLS[i][1] = 100
            BALLS[i][3] *= -1
        elif BALLS[i][1] > 500:
            BALLS[i][1] = 500
            BALLS[i][3] *= -1
        else:
            BALLS[i][1] += BALLS[i][3]


def main():
    initBalls()
    while True:
        for evnt in event.get():
            if evnt.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return
            elif evnt.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mx, my = evnt.pos
                button = evnt.button

        drawScreen()
        moveBalls()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Call `pygame.display.flip()` only once per frame.

```
def drawScreen(List):
    draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (0, 0, 800, 600))
    for x in range(40):
        BALLX=List[x][0]
        BALLY=List[x][1]
        draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (BALLX,BALLY),radius)
        # display.flip()  # Don't call `display.flip()` here.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (100-radius,100-radius,600+(2*radius),400+(2*radius)), 1)

        screen.blit(text,(300,height/20))

    pygame.display.flip()  # Call it here.
```

---

I also recommend to use a `pygame.time.Clock` to limit the frame rate.

```
# Define the font object as a global constant.
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 60)
# If the text doesn't change you can also define it here.
TEXT = FONT.render("PV=nRT", True, (0,0,0))
# Instantiate a clock to limit the frame rate.
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:  # `== True` is not needed.
    for evnt in event.get():
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
            # Better use `pygame.quit` and `sys.exit` to quit.
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    drawScreen(List)
    List = moveBall(List)

    clock.tick(30)  # Limit frame rate to 30 fps.
```

Comment: Thank you! It's so much smoother now!

Comment: @ashash you can also avoid to write the text and the frame in each iteration of the loop, you can move the 4 last lines in drawScreen above the loop

Comment: @PRMoureu good point. I'll add that to the example. ash ash, do you intend to change the text eventually during the run time or is it supposed to be constant?